# How do you position a nav bar in the center of the page with css

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to create a website and everything is going well except the nav bar wont move to the center of the screen, it did go to the center when i had the nav bar take up the entire page but i only want the nav bar to be as big as it needs to be but now i cant get it to go in the center of the page.

Here is my code below:

```
body {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
}

#header {
background-color: #b9fee2;
width: 1920px;
height: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a{
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a:visited {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: 35%;
}

#nav li {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

#nav a {
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

#nav a:link {
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
font-size: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}

#nav a:visited {
color: #000000;
}

#nav a:hover {
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
font-size: 30px;
}
#circle {
padding-top: 25px;
}

#webInfo {
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
font-size: 25px;
}

#webInfo p{
padding: 0px;
margin: 
}


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML         4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Portfolio - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png"/>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
            <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png"/>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="webInfo">
            <p>Hi, my name is Alex Trotter and this is my portfolio website</p>
            <p>below you will find some of work that I have created.</p>
            <p>Above you can navigate to different pages to learn more about me.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="exampleWork1"></div>
        <div id="exampleWork2"></div>
        <div id="exampleWork3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Snippet:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #b9fee2;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#nav a {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
#nav a:link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#nav a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#circle {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#webInfo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#webInfo p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin:
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="webInfo">
    <p>Hi, my name is Alex Trotter and this is my portfolio website</p>
    <p>below you will find some of work that I have created.</p>
    <p>Above you can navigate to different pages to learn more about me.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="exampleWork1"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork2"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork3"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Any reason the header is fixed width rather than 100%? http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/jkd569qc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `width: 100%` to `#nav`. But your html is invalid:

> **ul**: Permitted content zero or more li elements, eventually mixed with
>    and  elements.

I move `img` elements in `li`. Also `id` must be unique use class instead(I change elements with `id` `#circle` to `.circle` also update your css) and `img` element must have title and alt attributes. The correct version:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #b9fee2;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#nav a {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
#nav a:link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#nav a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.circle {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#webInfo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#webInfo p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin:
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <img class="circle" title="circle" alt="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
      <img class="circle" title="circle" alt="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="webInfo">
    <p>Hi, my name is Alex Trotter and this is my portfolio website</p>
    <p>below you will find some of work that I have created.</p>
    <p>Above you can navigate to different pages to learn more about me.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="exampleWork1"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork2"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork3"></div>
</div>
```

Solution with OP code:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #b9fee2;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#nav a {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
#nav a:link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#nav a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#circle {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#webInfo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#webInfo p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin:
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Alex Trotter</a></h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <img id="circle" src="images/circle.png" />
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="webInfo">
    <p>Hi, my name is Alex Trotter and this is my portfolio website</p>
    <p>below you will find some of work that I have created.</p>
    <p>Above you can navigate to different pages to learn more about me.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="exampleWork1"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork2"></div>
  <div id="exampleWork3"></div>
</div>
```

**References**

[ul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
div#header {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your ul to a block and set margin:auto to center the li elements of your ul

```
#nav{

 margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ardieziff/kqy985by/

Answer (score 1):

You could also make your #nav css like this to achieve the result your looking for.

```
#nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit.. changed your `#nav` to 100% width and edited the HTML of the `#nav` items (moved the image inside the anchor tags) take a look if this is what you mean: http://codepen.io/dirkpennings/pen/vLNYmx

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `display: inline-block` property for #nav? Simply remove it and the navigation is centered.

Answer (score 1):

Add these 2 simple **CSS** rules to `#nav`:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vxa0m7b/)